# Is it fair to use MIT licensed code in WordPress plugins?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, licensing

Is it fair to use an MIT licensed jQuery library inside a plugin and then sell it as a freemium plugin on WordPress.org?

Comment: what is "fair"? anyway, such question need to be asked in a law forum, not here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would normally not answer, but since I answered your other question once please allow me to.

If you check the [MIT licensing model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) you may read:

> MIT licensed software can be integrated into GPL software, but not the other way around.

Since WordPress themes and plugins should be GPLv2 I would say it is possible and legal.